# Twitter Authenticating request error to Twitter API v2 endpoints

Tags: twitter, azure-data-factory

I am getting the error while calling the data from twitter api v2 endpoint.
I have a Twitter Developer app created in the twitter developer portal where I have a twitter project and a connecting app. I was able to fetch the data but since last week it has been giving errors related to the authentication.
FYI, I have 3 business IDs which I am using to fetch the data. Below mentioned endpoint is giving data for another BU ID but having issue with one BU ID. I am still wondering if anything has changed on the Twitter api level.

Please pour your valuable suggestion.

**Approaches tried:**

1. checked the associated app and API Key, secret and token key and token secret. Everything is in place.
2. Regenerated the API Key, secret and token key and token secret and hit the endpoint, but it failed. I tested both in postman and ADF.

endpoint : https://api.twitter.com/2/users/XXXXXXX/tweets? tweet.fields=created_at, text, public_metrics, attachments, entities&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields-public_metrics

**error Detail:**

"detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints,
you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
"registration_url":"https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
"title":"Client Forbidden","required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access",
"reason":"client-not-enrolled",
"type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"}

[image]

Comment: did you able to find a fix for this? I'm also having the same issue.